# visual studio while loop suddenly stopping without completing all iterations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, while-loop, break

I'm working on visual studio 2010. Here I have a while loop and the code is as follows

```
while(cx!=ex && cy!=ey){
 //a* algorithm code inside
}
```

however after the 12th iteration the while loop suddenly breaks despite the condition remaining unfulfilled. There are no 'out of bounds' errors or anything like that. What could be causing this? What would be the best solution for this because I can say that there could be around a few to a hundred iterations. Thanks.

edit: code is in C++. Sorry.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, and therefore doesn't have `while` loops. It has a code editor, debugger, toolbox, and those sorts of things. It supports multiple **languages** that have while loops, so perhaps it would be better if you added the tag for the language you're using (and perhaps used it in the question as well).

Comment: A guess is that *one* of the values reaches its final limit. The loop terminates when *either* is true, it doesn't wait for both to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more code? (C++?)
If you're using MACROS for example, you could have "hidden" Break statements, etc.
Have you debugged it? Put a break point after the loop and check the values of cx and cy

Answer (score 0):

Since it's highly unlikely that the while loop suddenly stops with no reason
I recommend you start by making sure that the while condition is really false.

You didn't state what language you're using, in C# you can use:

```
 Debug.Print(cx == ex);
 Debug.Print(cy == ey);
```

This should help you find the problem. If there is a problem in your code, one of them will return `true`

**Update:**
For C++ the method is the same, check the values of the 4 variables right after the loop ends.